# How to join whosonfirst results with other layers? Pelias API

Tags: pelias

I've configured Pelias API and see that my results don't include whosonfirst locality

my API results:

[image]

api.geocode.earth results:

[image]

I do have configured all services (placeholder, pip, libpostal) running correctly

Config for whosonfirst import job:

```
 "whosonfirst": {
            "sqlite": true,
            "datapath": "/data/whosonfirst",
            "dataHost": "https://data.geocode.earth/wof/dist/sqlite/whosonfirst-data-admin-ua-latest.db.bz2",
            "importPostalcodes": "true",
            "countryCode": "UA",
            "importPlace": [ 101752483 ]
        }
```

I can see some data from whosonfirst are imported to elastic succesfully:

[image]

How can I add this information to my venues/streets layers results?